# Sendgrid smtp cannot verify sender identity

Tags: django, email, smtp, sendgrid

I have a Django application that uses sendgrid’s smtp relay for sending emails. However I am receiving a 550 error.

I authenticated my domain in sendgrid and I added a send user with the “from” email no-reply@mydomain.com. This email however doesn’t actually exist, is this the cause of my error?

If so wouldn’t this mean I have to setup an email server to use no-reply@mydomain.com, and isn’t the whole point of sendgrid to not have to create a email server?

This is a point of confusion for me because I thought sendgrid authenticates your domain to act as a email server for it

I Set the following env variables:

```
EMAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_HOST_USER=“apikey”EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=SG.*********
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL=no-  reply@mydomain.com
```

My error log is:

> “smtplib.SMTPDataError: (550, b'The from address does not match a
> verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is
> resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-
> email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity requirements')”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [Domain Authentication](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication) to enable all addresses from that domain, incl your norepl@mydomain.com.

> When sending email, you must set Domain Name System (DNS) records on the domain to:
>
> 1. Communicate to receiving email servers that you own the domain the email was sent from.
> 2. Verify that you have given the sending email server permission to send email on behalf of the domain.

PS: This might also help you in avoiding that your mails get [flagged as spam](https://sendgrid.com/blog/why-are-my-emails-going-to-spam/).

Comment: Thank you, and this email doesn’t need to actually “exist” correct? As in I can put anythinghere@mydomain.com (I never created the no-reply email). 

I authenticated my domain on sendgrid, so I guess the issue must be that I actually have to go to my domain on GoDaddy and set the permissions to allow others to send emails on its behalf?

Comment: Correct, that email does not need to exist. I'm not sure what GoDaddy step you are referring to as there shouldn't be a step after the successful domain authentication mentioned [here](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041791233-Configuring-and-Troubleshooting-CNAME-records-on-GoDaddy-domains).